# Subfields of splitting field

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

I recently started learnig field and Galois theory and was given this problem:

Given polynomial over Q

$\displaystyle f=2x^{6} \ −\ 4x^{5} \ −\ 3x^{4} \ −\ x^{3} \ +\ 8x^{2} \ +\ 6x\ −\ 6\ \in \ Z[ x] \ $

find splitting field K of f, and determine degree [K : Q].

Then find all subfields M of K satisfying [K : M]=2.

I managed to find splitting field K as $\displaystyle \mathbb{Q}\left( \sqrt[3] 2,\zeta _{3,}\sqrt{3}\right) \ $
and [K : Q] = 12

where $\displaystyle \zeta _{3}$ is 3rd root of unity.

I also think that galois group  of f is non abellian.

However when I try to figure out to what group it is precisely I get stuck.
If I missunderstood something or made mistake, please let me know. If not, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* We have
$$
f=(x^3 - 2)(2x^2 - 6x + 3)(x + 1).
$$

Further references:

[Galois group of a reducible polynomial over $\mathbb {Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52680/galois-group-of-a-reducible-polynomial-over-mathbb-q)

[Galois group of a reducible polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78347/galois-group-of-a-reducible-polynomial)

Comment: Thank you, I managed to solve it on my own last night.